# Adobe Air Binary Sockets

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, air

When I Connect To My Socket Over My Intranet, Everything Works Fine:

```
var Sock:Socket=new Socket("192.168.1.100",2222);
```

But When I Set Up Port-Forwarding And Try To Connect Using My Real IP, I Get Error 2031:

```
var Sock:Socket=new Socket("76.18.24.118",2222);
```

What Am I Missing?

Comment: Please describe the network layout. Are you trying connecting from outside (internet) into your private network through port forwarding on the border router?

Comment: This could be an issue with crossdomain policy of Flash Player. If you are connecting to another server, it has to provide crossdomain entry allowing you host domain to connect. If it is, check out [Setting up a socket policy file server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html)